# How to create Javadoc custom tag in Ant script

Tags: ant, tags, javadoc

Currently i am trying to create custom javadoc tags through ant script to declare some attributes in the class level comment.

I need to create one custom tag which is similar to @param tag in the method level. This tag can be declared n number of time in the class level.

```
/**
* @argument name of the argument1: description1
* @argument name of the argument2: description2
*/
public class MainClass{
}
```

And i am expecting the javadoc to be generated as below:

```
Arguments:
name of the argument1: - description1
name of the argument2: - description2
```

Currently I am using below syntax to create custom tag and the below syntax generates JavaDoc, appending all argument as one text due to this unable to split the argument.

`<tag name="<Name of the Tag>" scope="all" description="<Description about the tag>"/>`

```
Arguments:
name of the argument1: - description1, name of the argument2: - description2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the `<tag>` tag in Ant is just a way to specify the `-tag` parameter of the `javadoc` tool. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/javadoc/javadoc-command.htm#JSJAV-GUID-C27CE557-E5C6-4688-9FA5-9E9DE886A569).

The `-tag` parameter is not very customizable with respect to its output. So I don‘t think you can achieve what you want that way.

However, you can implement your own tag handler (or, as Javadoc calls it: Taglet) and fully customize its output. See the [Taglet documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/taglet/overview.html) for more information.

In Ant, you can then use the `<taglet>` tag to use it in the build process.

Comment: Thanks for your response Stefan. I have tried this option also but i am not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response Stefan. I have tried this option also but i am not succeed.

````
         <taglet name="<packagename>.<Classname">
                        <path>
                            <pathelement location="bin"/>
                          </path>
                     </taglet>
                </javadoc>```

Taglet is registering properly but i get below warning and the tag information is not present in the generated html page.

     [javadoc] Registered Taglet packagename.ArgumentsTaglet ...
  [javadoc] Standard Doclet version 1.8.0_121
  [javadoc] Building tree for all the packages and classes...
  [javadoc] Building index for all the packages and classes...
  [javadoc] Building index for all classes...
  [javadoc] Generating C:\temp\Projects\TagletCreation\docs\help-doc.html...
  [javadoc] Note: Custom tags that were not seen:  @arguments
  [javadoc] 100 warnings

Note: I am using Java 1.8 version.
````